# How to use ES6 filter function with OR statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this:

```
var array = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: ""}, {something: "else"}, {id: "3"}, {id: "4"}];
```

And I'm trying to filter it like this, with an OR statement:

```
array.filter(x => x.id != "" || x.id != null);
```

I'm trying to filter the array by taking the objects where the ID is not an empty string, nor is the ID null.

I am expecting this:

```
[{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: "3"}, {id: "4"}];
```

I get this (just same array):

```
[{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: ""}, {something: "else"}, {id: "3"}, {id: "4"}];
```

```js
var array = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: ""}, {something: "else"}, {id: "3"}, {id: "4"}];
var filteredArray = array.filter(x => x.id != "" || x.id != null);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I filter an array with an OR statement like that?

Comment: "*nor*" translates into "***and** is also not*".

Answer (score 0):

I'm really stupid...

I need to use an AND statement instead of an OR.

```
array.filter(x => x.id != "" && x.id != null);
```

```js
var array = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}, {id: ""}, {something: "else"}, {id: "3"}, {id: "4"}];
var filteredArray = array.filter(x => x.id != "" && x.id != null);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Alternatively use `x => !(x.id == "" || x.id == null)`

Answer (score 0):

You've got your logic backwards - you want to filter on items whose id is not the empty string *AND* (using the `&&` operator) not null:

```
array.filter(x => x.id != "" && x.id != null)
// => [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"}]
```